# F#: Calling native functions with custom type parameters

Tags: c++, f#, interop, native

I'm calling into a native DLL from F#.  It's proven pretty simple for functions that take no arguments or only basic types, but I'm having a lot of trouble getting my code to work otherwise.

The C++ code is:

```
struct CatDef
{
    uint8_t cat;
    uint8_t arrogance;

    CatDef() : cat(0), arrogance(0) {}
};

struct HomeInfo
{
    enum { MAX_CATDEF = 5 };
    enum {
        LONE_CAT = 0x01,
    };
    CatDef  cd[MAX_CATDEF];
    uint8_t  notoriety;
    uint8_t  etc;

    HomeInfo()
        : notoriety(0), etc(0)
    {
        memset(cd, 0, sizeof(cd));
    }

    size_t howBig() const
    {
        size_t hb = 0;
        for (; hb < MAX_CATDEF; ++hb)
            if (!cd[hb].cat)
                break;
        return hb;
    }
};

struct HomeQuery
{
    char addr[ADDR_LENGTH];    // ADDR_LENGTH is 1024
    char verifiedAddr[ADDR_LENGTH];
    HomeInfo homeData;
    unsigned int id;
    Status  st;    // Status is an enum

    HomeQuery()
        : homeData()
        , id(0)
        , st(Unprocessed)
    {
        memset(addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
        memset(verifiedAddr, 0, sizeof(verifiedAddr));
    }
};

__declspec(dllexport) bool GetHomeInfo(
    HomeQuery* queries, size_t qCount, void (*callback)(HomeQuery*, size_t) = 0);
```

So far, I have this for F#:

```
[<Struct>]
type CatDef =
    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable cat : uint8
    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable arrogance : uint8

[<Struct>]
type HomeInfo =
    [<DefaultValue; MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5)>]
    val mutable cd : CatDef array
    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable notoriety : uint8
    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable etc : uint8

[<Struct>]
type HomeQuery =
    [<DefaultValue; MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 1024)>]
    val mutable addr : string
    [<DefaultValue; MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 1024)>]
    val mutable verifiedAddr : string
    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable homeData : HomeInfo
    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable id : uint32
    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable st : int

type HomeQueryCallback = delegate of (HomeQuery array * uint) -> unit

module private Wrapper =
    [<DllImport(
        "Homes.dll",
        EntryPoint = "?GetHomeInfo@People@@NA_WBYUHomeQuery@1@IP6AX0I@Z@Z",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
    extern bool GetHomeInfo(HomeQuery[] queries, uint qCount, HomeQueryCallback callback)

[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module HomeLib =
    let getHomeInfo queries = Wrapper.GetHomeInfo (queries, uint queries.Length, null)
```

For rules about type marshalling, I have been referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/type-marshaling#default-rules-for-marshaling-common-types.

When I call `HomeLib.getHomeInfo` and step into the native library (Homes.dll), I see that the fields of the first (and only) item in the `HomeQuery` array contain garbled information.  (`qCount` and `callback` are uncorrupted, and contain the expected values.)  As you can see, I've tried adding `MarshalAs` attributes to a few fields, but this hasn't had any positive effect.  Neither has decorating any of the types with `[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I got it worked out.

For anyone who might care, my F# code worked with just a couple of changes:

1. I changed `UnmanagedType.LPStr` to `UnmanagedType.ByValTStr`
2. In the `extern` function declaration, I decorated `HomeQuery[] queries` with `[<In; Out>]` (i.e. `[<In; Out>]HomeQuery[] queries`).

That's all.

Comment: I shall do so, LSM07, once StackOverflow permits it.  (I have to wait a day.)